# select Duplicate Records in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `tblDoc` and `tblrev`

**tblDoc**

```
DocID DocNum
1     Doc-001
2     Doc-002
3     Doc-003
4     Doc-004   
5     Doc-005
```

**tblRev**

```
revID DocID  ReV
1       2     A
2       2     A
3       1     B
4       3     c
```

I need to select `DocID` and `revID` of the duplicates in `tblRev` where a duplicate record is known as with the same `DocID` and Rev.

```
ex: revID 1,2 is a duplicate
```

plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT
        [DocID]
      , [ReV]
      , COUNT([revID]) as [Count]
    FROM tblRev
    GROUP BY
        [DocID]
      , [ReV]
),
DuplicateRevID AS
(
    SELECT
        R.[revID]
      , R.[DocID]
    FROM Duplicates D
        INNER JOIN tblRev R ON
            D.[DocID] = R.[DocID]
        AND D.[ReV] = R.[ReV]
    WHERE
        D.[Count] > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM DuplicateRevID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT revID
FROM TblRev
WHERE Rev IN
(
  SELECT ReV
  FROM tblRev
  GROUP BY Rev, DocId
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Rev can be duplicated but what should not happen is duplicating the combination of DocID and ReV both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select tr.revID,tr.DocID  FROM tblDoc td 
Inner Join tblRev tr on  td.DocID = tr.DocID 
GROUP BY tr.revID,tr.DocID  
Having count(td.DocID )> 1
```

Comment: You can't do that. You will get the following error: Column 'tblRev.revID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try Now GROUP BY tr.revID,tr.DocID